# Creating Weblogic domain with Admin Server and managed servers on different machines

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

I am trying to create Weblogic domain where Admin Server and managed servers on different machines. However I am unable to find any steps which would allow me to do so. The config.sh script always creates an Admin Server. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create managed servers/clusters as well at the time of the domain creation itself at least using 'Graphical Mode' config.sh wizard

If for some reason you are not getting the graphical wizard when config.sh is invoked try checking your DISPLAY variable.

Also check the [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/docs81/confgwiz/newdom.html#1058958) for reference.